# Is our Beta label being removed?

Tags: discussion

Quantum Computing and Matter Modeling just learned that their Beta labels are being removed. Is it happening here too?

Comment: Wow, Matter Modeling (in such a short space of time)? Congrats. PS How did you find out?

Comment: @thesimplifire appatently a lot of sites will leave Beta soon (there's a Meta post on quantum computing SE). PS, I just voted for you in the Math.SE election!

Comment: @TheSimpliFire We heard from the CMs yesterday in our mod chat. I'm not sure how many sites are leaving Beta.

Comment: @Tyberius nice to see you here! Do you sporadically browse the OR meta or were you directed here somehow?!

Comment: I tend to peak in on other sites Meta's occasionally, though it had been a while with OR. I actually check mainly to see if OR had also graduate after seeing the feature post on Quantum Computing.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Interestingly, if the only criteria were those described on [Medical Science](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1313), then OR should also be graduating. 1. Its been active more than 6 months. 2. 2,200 open questions (>1000) 3. 356 unanswered open questions (<30%). So if you haven't gotten any notification yet, it may be worth clarifying with CMs if there was other criteria.

Comment: Wow @Tyberius you really look at all the Meta sites!